# Reparameterizing a model in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to optimize the parameters of a simple model which is implemented using the PyTorch library. For the purpose of optimization, I would like to use a different representation of the parameters than that which is specified by the model class. I would like, in particular, to represent my parameters as a single vector (rather than two vectors as in this example).

I can convert from `model.parameters()` (which is an `Iterable`) to the desired vector representation using `parameters_to_vector` from `torch.nn.utils.convert_parameters`. However, when I try to label this vector as a leaf (with `detach` and `requires_grad_`), and use it to populate the original parameters of the model object with `vector_to_parameters`, then it appears that the computation graph is not made aware of what is happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.utils.convert_parameters import *

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

model = SimpleModel()

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.size())
# this prints:
## linear.weight torch.Size([1, 10])
## linear.bias torch.Size([1])

loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

vparams = parameters_to_vector(model.parameters()).detach().clone().requires_grad_(True)

# populate model.parameters() from vparams
vector_to_parameters(vparams, model.parameters())

input_data = torch.randn(1, 10)
output = model(input_data)
target = torch.randn(1, 1)

loss = loss_function(output, target)
# loss.backward()  ## if we do this, then vparams.grad is None

## this one works, but we wanted to use vparams:
# vgrads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, model.linear.weight)[0]   

## this gives an error:
vgrads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, vparams)[0]
## "One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph."
```

I also tried performing the vector slices manually, but this doesn't fix the error. E.g.:

```
model.linear.weight.data.copy_(vparams[0:10].view_as(model.linear.weight.data))
```

or

```
model.linear.weight = nn.Parameter(vparams[0:10].view_as(model.linear.weight.data))
```

I'm somewhat new to PyTorch, but I've read that it is possible with PyTorch to compute gradients through slices, so it seems that what I'm attempting should be possible.

Am I missing something about the `torch.nn.Parameter` class which is used by PyTorch models? Are members of this class required to be "leaves" in the computation graph? Here is a smaller example that omits the `nn.Module` subclass and just tries to create a `nn.Parameter` object from a "slice":

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], requires_grad=True)

#b = nn.Parameter(a[1]) # "RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph."
#b = torch.Tensor(a[1]) # "IndexError: slice() cannot be applied to a 0-dim tensor."
b = a[1] # works

g = torch.autograd.grad(b, a)[0]
```

From the error message, it seems that PyTorch is not able to differentiate through an `nn.Parameter` initialization. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how `vector_to_parameters` works. Look at the source code:

```py
def vector_to_parameters(vec: torch.Tensor, parameters: Iterable[torch.Tensor]) -> None:
    r"""Convert one vector to the parameters

    Args:
        vec (Tensor): a single vector represents the parameters of a model.
        parameters (Iterable[Tensor]): an iterator of Tensors that are the
            parameters of a model.
    """
    # Ensure vec of type Tensor
    if not isinstance(vec, torch.Tensor):
        raise TypeError('expected torch.Tensor, but got: {}'
                        .format(torch.typename(vec)))
    # Flag for the device where the parameter is located
    param_device = None

    # Pointer for slicing the vector for each parameter
    pointer = 0
    for param in parameters:
        # Ensure the parameters are located in the same device
        param_device = _check_param_device(param, param_device)

        # The length of the parameter
        num_param = param.numel()
        # Slice the vector, reshape it, and replace the old data of the parameter
        param.data = vec[pointer:pointer + num_param].view_as(param).data

        # Increment the pointer
        pointer += num_param
```

`vector_to_parameters` assigns the values in `vec` to the parameters in `parameters`. This updates the `data` values in `parameters`, but there is no autograd link between `vec` and the updated parameters.

When you do a forward pass, you use the parameters in the model state dict and the gradients flow back to those parameters.

For example, when you run the following code, you get gradients populated at `model.linear.weight.grad`, because that is a leaf parameter of the computation. `vparams` has no involvement in the computation, so there's no gradient chain back to `vparams`.

```py
vector_to_parameters(vparams, model.parameters())

input_data = torch.randn(1, 10)
output = model(input_data)
target = torch.randn(1, 1)

loss = loss_function(output, target)
loss.backward()

print(model.linear.weight.grad)
```

Comment: So how do you solve the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do and why it is important to represent parameters as a single vector?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why it would be useful to have a mathematical quantity represented as a vector rather than as a list or a tuple. I'm guessing that the answer to my question is that it is not possible to have the model parameters depend on other quantities, but I'd be interested in hearing from someone who knows why.

Comment: If you can't articulate a specific use case that requires manipulating parameters in this way, I can't help you.